# redirect all product_details.php?id=p_id to mysite/products/product_name

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, woocommerce

i have configured my Wordpress website product detail's permalink to follow `"Mysite/products/product_name"` url pattern
but the old pattern `"mysite.com/product_details.php?id=1"` still working.

is there any way i can redirect the old url to new one .

Comment: Does the new permalink structure work? meaning both urls would work?

Comment: Are you looking to forward this for SEO purposes? Both are valid URLs and yes, you *could* put a redirect on the old pattern, but I'm not sure you would want to.

Comment: @TeeJayEss yes i want to forward the old url to new one for SEO reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/.

Comment: using plugin solved problem and easy to handle as the manual approach is very complicated ...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not very well supported in Wordpress itself...

I would suggest, as the others here are saying; to apply manual redirects using a plugin. Have a look at how that approach is done safely in this article: https://www.wpexplorer.com/change-permalinks-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

**Setting Up Manual Redirects**

Sometimes, the plugin won’t pick up on the redirect you need, maybe because you want to redirect one post to another or you want to redirect a URL on your domain to a different domain.

In this case, you’ll need to set up a manual redirect.

**Go to Tools > Redirection and scroll down to the Add new redirection section.
add new redirect**

**In the Source URL field, type or paste in the URL you want to redirect from. In the Target URL field, type or paste in the URL you want to redirect to. In the Group field, either leave it as Redirections (the default) or select Modified posts if you’re directing from an old post to a newer version.** This will give browsers information telling them what kind of redirect it is.

Finally, click the Add Redirect button and your manual redirect will be added to the list of redirects.

Comment: I tried your option but its not working ... the error i get when i click on Check redirect is "Agent: Not using Redirection"

Answer (score 0):

Put something like the followng in your `product_details.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Meta Tag</title>
      <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = <?php
            echo "\"1; url = products/"
            echo $_GET['id']
            echo "\""
      ?> />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>redirecting...</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

[source for redirection part](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-redirect-from-an-HTML-page)

You might want to replace the $_GET['id'] part with snippet that translates the `product id` to the according `product name` and echo that into the link

Comment: How to get the permalink for pid in product_details.php

Comment: the $_GET variable contains all the form data, so the stuff behind the question mark in your url. `$_GET['pid']` contains the `15` you give in `http://foo/bar.php?pid=15`

-->[tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_superglobals_get.asp)<--

Comment: also be advised: I did not test the code I provided above

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the `product_details.php` file and add the code as below.

```php
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['id']) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://YOUR_DOMAIN.TLD/?p=" . $_GET['id']); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

Please replace `YOUR_DOMAIN.TLD` with your domain.

The above code will redirect to your main site with id and it will generate the correct link and redirect.